# Wait command in DCL before executing next command

Tags: terminal, openvms, dcl

Is there a command in DCL that will wait for a specified amount of time before executing the next command. I am making a simple command file that will ping a user specified IP Address, wait 5 seconds then repeat the ping process.

Currently I have managed to ask the user for an IP Address which is then pinged.

```
$ INQUIRE PINGTEST "Enter IP Address"
$ TCPIP PINGTEST
$ <wait command>
$ <repeat TCPIP PINGTEST>
```

Comment: @Svend Thank you for that, I did google it but clearly not good enough. I've only just started to learn about OpenVMS and DCL. If you have any recommended help material that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided by @Svend DCL supports a WAIT command formatted as *WAIT delta-time*

So for example if I wanted to wait 5 seconds before executing the next command the code would be as follows:

```
$ INQUIRE PINGTEST "Enter IP Address"
$ TCPIP PINGTEST
$! WAIT time format hour:minute:second.hundredth 
$ WAIT 00:00:05
$ TCPIP PINGTEST
```

Comment: you can also provide an absolute time ``sh ti`` shows 
``7-NOV-2019 13:58:48`` now if I do ``wait 7-nov-2019 14:00`` it will wait until 14:00, see https://www.parsec.com/os/openvms/undocumented.php